# Uploading files to Firebase Storage from Android application

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am making an App in Android Studio and I am using Firebase Storage to store user information in individual text files, to later be uploaded to the app's user dashboard.  I have written all the code to do this and I have followed the Firebase documentation to the best of my ability.  When I run my app (tested on my Motorola moto e5 phone) everything runs perfectly, and then the file with the user information is created. Then it is supposed to be uploaded to the Firebase Storage section, and then it should be destroyed.  I know that the first and last events happened.

***Problem***

However, when I go into Firebase to check that the file is there it is not.  So I go to check to see if Android Studio returned any errors and I see no errors and that everything ran smoothly, but ***I don't see the files in firebase that were supposed to be uploaded***.  So then I looked all over the internet, fourm after fourm, documentation after documentation, and I tried it all.  If you find something that might help me that I haven't found please kindly share the link.  Also if you know what the problem is please share.

***Troubleshooting Methods***

To be more specific these are some things I have tried:

- Clean Project
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Change SDK Version in the dependencies in the `build.gradle` file and made sure they were all up to date and tried old ones too
- Wrote the example code they give in the documentation in a different project and it still didn't work
- Kept writing code to see if the file was hidden and the Storage Reference returned null
- Tried removing the `file.delete();` line

***Code***

This method when called should create a "goal" the user wants to accomplish by saving their input in a file called `0.txt`, `1.txt`, `2.txt` and so on.  Then the method should upload the file to Firebase Storage, and that's where the problem is.  It won't appear in the database.

```
private void createGoal(String activity, String timeframe, String number, String unit) throws IOException {

     //creates an instance of the Main Dashboard class inorder to access the variable counterString.
     MainDashboard dBoard = new MainDashboard();

     //Names the 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, and so on
     file = new File(dBoard.counterString + ".txt");

     //Creates the actual file
     file.createNewFile();

     //Creates the writer object that will write to the file
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

     //Writes to the text file
     writer.write(activity + " : " + "0 / "+ number + " " + unit + " in " + timeframe);

     //Closes the Writer
     writer.close();

     //Creates a Uri from the file to be uploaded
     upload = Uri.fromFile(new File(activity + ".txt"));

     //Uploads the file exactly as the documentation says, but it doesn't work
     UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(upload);

     //Deletes the file from the local system
     file.delete();
}
```

Any Ideas Are Appreciated.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `putFile` Firebase **starts** uploading the data in the background, so that your user can continue to use the app. But your code immediately calls `delete` on the local file after that, which means you're deleting the local file before Firebase has completed (or possibly even started) uploading it.

The trick is to [monitor the upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) as shown in the Firebase documentation, and only delete the local file once the upload has completed.

Based on the example from that documentation:

```
// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
        System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
    }
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("Upload is paused");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        // ...

        //Deletes the file from the local system
        file.delete();

    }
});
```